# Which Compile elements are required in SDK-format CSPROJ?

Tags: c#, msbuild, csproj

I am using the "new" SDK format project style for my C# projects. I am still using .NET Framework 4.8 and it's a winforms application. I have defined the project like so:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <!-- etc... -->
  </PropertyGroup>
</project>
```

I noticed that without any explicit `Compile` and `EmbeddedResource` elements with consideration to `*.cs` and `*.resx` files (respectively), my `Form.cs`, `Form.Designer.cs`, and `Form.resx` files get grouped properly in Visual Studio 2019.

They get listed like so in the Solution Explorer:

```
+ Form.cs
  - Form.Designer.cs
  - Form.resx
```

However, oddly the resource file itself (the one at `Properties/Resources.resx`) is not grouped appropriately:

```
+ Resources.Designer.cs
+ Resources.resx
```

They both show up as sibling files and not nested. If I throw this XML into the csproj:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Then I get the expected hierarchy in the Solution Explorer:

```
+ Resources.resx
  - Resources.Designer.cs
```

Are the `Compile` elements required for resource files, or is this a bug? What is the correct setup here?

Note that in the latest version of Jetbrains Rider, it shows the proper nesting between both changes; It's only Visual Studio 2019 that shows a hierarchical difference.

I'm not able to find any specific documentation on MSDN about this. I am aware of [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj) but it doesn't seem to specifically address this topic.

Versions Tested:

- Rider: 2020.1.4
- Visual Studio: 16.6.5

Answer (score 0):

SDK projects only generate default `<Compile Include="*\*.cs />` elements. Your element is altering the default behaviour by adding `DesignTime`, `AutoGen` and `DependUpon` properties, by using `<Compile Update="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">`.

More info on the system generated `<Compile />` elements can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview#default-includes-and-excludes